# How to run python script at login screen?

Tags: python, lightdm

I use a python script to set brightness to zero.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import dbus 
bus = dbus.SessionBus() 
proxy = bus.get_object('org.gnome.SettingsDaemon',
                       '/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power') 
iface = dbus.Interface(proxy,dbus_interface='org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen')
iface.SetPercentage(0)
```

I've put it in Startup Applications. It works only when I login. There is full brightness at login screen.

Where should I put this so that it sets brightness to zero at login screen?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of this, but i recall that i have used /etc/rc.local in similar situations. add a line that executes your script there.

And then there is upstart that might work. But i have no experience with that except a script that i found to autostart deluged

Your startup script would probably look something like

```
start on startup

script
  python - <<END
    import dbus

    bus = dbus.SessionBus() 
    proxy = bus.get_object('org.gnome.SettingsDaemon',
                   '/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power') 
    iface = dbus.Interface(proxy,dbus_interface='org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen')
    iface.SetPercentage(0)

  END
end script
```

Upstart resource http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Nice, but you should probably add some pre-requisites to this. I assume (no testing) that you will need both dbus and ligthdm running for this to work.

Comment: Yeah i did not test it, and you are right those probably needs to be running for this to work